# Cypress - adding Cucumber

Tags: typescript, cypress

This is a very basic question, but since I've never been a frontend developer, js and ts is pretty new to me.

I'm trying to add Cucumber functionality to a Cypress test suite. I've installed the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor package, but I'm running into problem when all the howto's and info I can find use js as examples.

I'm supposed to put this into the index.js file:

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

Since the test suite has an index.ts file instead, this naturally can't be copy-pasted in. How do I convert it to .ts?

Answer (score 2):

That particular code should work in `index.ts` as

```js
import { default as cucumber } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor'
// or just 
import cucumber from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor'

export default (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

Installs:

```js
npm install --save-dev cypress-cucumber-preprocessor
npm install --save-dev @types/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor
```

In general [cypress-realworld-app](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app) has typescript as a source of examples (but not cucumber).

Comment: Thanks. That gives me the following error: "TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor'". Apparently, the cucumber preprocessor isn't (completely) installed? I've run npm install --save-dev cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, which is all the following howto specifies: https://blog.knoldus.com/cypress-with-cucumber/

Comment: And I missed the `from`, but that's something else.

Comment: For the first you need this types package [https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor)

Comment: That worked. However, when I add the "on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())" line cypress returns: "TypeError: cypress_cucumber_preprocessor_1.default is not a function".

Comment: If I remove the accisting default import and use the one you gave me above (it's unused, anyway), I get complains that "TS7006: Parameter 'on' implicitly has an 'any' type." Same for 'config'. I can ask IntelliJ to infer parameter types from use, which removes the error, but cypress still complains and refuses to load.

Comment: In VS Code it's not as drastic - just a warning, Cypress loads ok.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work here, and no one dealing with Cypress seems to know one bit about TypeScript. So I'll just have to give up on Cypress.